# Probability of getting at-least one of the subsequent two throw

Tags: probability

[image]

I have solved the question  by considering  the probability of the first through =.5

therefore the the probability of  getting latest one of the subsequent two through  =  $1- \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{4} \times\frac{1}{4}$

Problem is that, the answer is given $\frac{7}{16}$. Am I missing something?

**[I am pretty bad at typing so I have attached the image, sorry for this]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of hitting on the second throw is $1/4$. The probability of missing on the second and then hitting on the third is $(3/4)(1/4)$. Add.

Alternately, first find the probability of the complement, the probability of two misses in a row. This is $(3/4)^2$, so our required probability is $1-(3/4)^2$.

**Remark:** Note that much of the information we were given is irrelevant. Her hitting rate on a first throw does not matter, since she in fact missed. So is her success rate after a success.

Answer (score 1):

Let L be the loss on any throw, W be the Win on any throw:

What you want is

$$P(L,W,L)+P(L,W,W)+P(L,L,W) =\frac{1}{4}.\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}.\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4}.\frac{1}{4} = \frac{7}{16}$$

Comment: How do you get from the LHS to the RHS?  The *joint* probability $P(L, W, L) = (1/2)(1/4)(1/4) = 1/32$.  Even if we treat it as the conditional probability $P(W, L \mid L)$, we end up with $(1/4)(1/4) = 1/16$.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Brian Tung, As Andre has indicated that the loss in the first throw is known, given that, let us take the first case, P(L,W,L). the probability that the second throw  is a win given first throw is loss is $\frac{1}{4}$.  The probability that the third throw is a Loss given that the second throw is a Win is $\frac{3}{4}$.  Apply similar reasoning for the remainder of the cases and you would get the required probability.  My notation is simplified.  Other that that there is no fault in the reasoning.

Comment: But the probability that the third row is a loss given that the second throw is a win is $1/4$, not $3/4$.  The probabilities seem correct in the second case, but in the third case, we again should have $(3/4)(1/4)$.  The end result is correct, but I think your correspondence is in error, no?

Comment: @Brian Tung, I am sorry, you are right, correspondence is in error, I am extremely sorry.  I will change it.

Comment: No need for apologies—I just wanted to let you know, so that you could fix it.  (I think, technically, I can fix it, but that seems heavy-handed.)